# My "Description" in gallery doesn't accept formatting/html

Tags: gallery, description

that's the part of my attachment-page that's responsible for showing image description, which I put when adding a new media (I'm using standard wordpress gallery):
< ?php the_excerpt(); ?>
Well, it shows the description, but it ignores all formatting/html.
I can't put a link inside it, can't bold font, nor even put a < br />!
The formatting stays in description field after saving, it doesn't reset or something.
How I can solve that?

Comment: You have to alter the way excerpt is generated. See [Improving WordPress' the_excerpt() template tag](http://aaronrussell.co.uk/legacy/improving-wordpress-the_excerpt/)